# How to set java class path in Flume-env.sh?

Tags: flume

I am trying to append twitter data into HDFS using flume. I am not able to set the Java classpath in `flume-env.sh` file. It is showing that you don't have permissions to do it. How can I edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Configuring Flume to use Twitter as Source](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2015/12/configuring-flume-to-use-twitter-as.html) for step by step instructions on how to configure flume to ingest Twitter data

Answer (score 0):

Before edit this flume-env.sh using nano command in Linux OS use sudo command.
ex: sudo nano flume-env.sh
It will ask for user current user password provide the same to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to confirm you have the right permissions for editing "flume-env.sh" file. File must be in **$APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/flume-env.sh**

Then you can edit the file (It is my own configuration) for set additional things to the classpath

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx16392m"

FLUME_CLASSPATH="/path/to/the/flume/classpath"
```